# MDLabel is not scrolling

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

This is the sample code.The text Inside the Label is not scrolling
Can any one help me on this.

```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen

class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen=Screen()
        self.s=ScrollView(size_hint=(1,0.1),pos_hint={"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5})
        self.l=MDLabel(text="hello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n")
        self.s.add_widget(self.l)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.s)
        return self.screen
        
Main().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `size_hint_y=None` and then set the height of the label to the size of the actual text.

```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen


class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.s = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, 0.1), pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5})
        self.l = MDLabel(
            size_hint_y=None, # Set size_hint to None
            text="hello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n hello\n hello \n hello \n hello  \nhello\nhello\n"
        )
        self.l.texture_update() # Update the size of label text
        self.l.height = self.l.texture_size[1] # Set the height of the label to the height of the text
        self.s.add_widget(self.l)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.s)
        return self.screen


Main().run()
```